# How to determine which point is closest to another?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, distance

I have two lists, the **first contains x, y coordinates for the center of a rectangle** and the **second contains x, y, w, h coordinates for the end points of the line that connects the rectangles.** The **end points of the lines are x1 = x, y1 = y, x2 = x + w, y2 = y + h.** I am trying to find **which end point of the line is closest to the center of the rectangle.** I know that I need to use Pythagoras' Theorem to **calculate the distance between the end points to the center of the rectangle** but I am having issues correctly determining **which of them are closest to the center of the correct rectangle.**

[Interconnected Rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPOwm.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVF1d.png)

In this example cx1, cy1 closest end point is supposed to be x1, y1 and cx2, cy2 closest end points are supposed to be (x2, y2), (x3, y3) and (x5, y5). The same goes for the other rectangles. The blue lines represent which red dot connects to which green dot.

```
distance = []
#masterStruc contains the x and y coordinates for the center of the rectangle
for z in range(len(masterStruc)):
    cx = masterStruc[z][3]
    cy = masterStruc[z][4]
    #lineStruc contains the x, y, w, h coordinates for the end points of the line
    for n in range(len(lineStruc)):
        lx = lineStruc[n][0]
        ly = lineStruc[n][1]
        lw = lineStruc[n][2]
        lh = lineStruc[n][3]

        #Calculating the distances from the end points to the center of a rectangle
        dist1 = int(math.sqrt((lx-cx)**2 + (ly-cy)**2))
        dist2 = int(math.sqrt((lx+lw-cx)**2 + (ly+lh-cy)**2))

        #Loop to compare which of the distances are closest to the center
        for j in range(len(lineStruc)):
            xx = lineStruc[n][0]
            yy = lineStruc[n][1]
            xw = lineStruc[n][2]
            yh = lineStruc[n][3]

            #Calculating the distances from the end points to the center of a rectangle
            dist3 = int(math.sqrt((xx-cx)**2 + (yy-cy)**2))
            dist4 = int(math.sqrt((xx+xw-cx)**2 + (yy+yh-cy)**2))

            #Checking if the distance of the end points are closer
            if(dist1 < dist4):
                lx1 = lx
                ly1 = ly
            elif(dist1 < dist3):
                lx1 = lx
                ly1 = ly
            elif(dist2 < dist4):
                lx1 = lx + lw
                ly1 = ly + lh
            else:
                lx1 = lx + lw
                ly1 = ly + lh
    #Storing the points of the closest end point and center of rectangle
    distance.append([cx, cy, lx1, ly1])
```

Comment: Add an example as well to make it clear

Comment: Scipy has kd trees which can be used to answer questions about a set of points in space efficiently, like what the closest point to some location is, what the closest pair of points is, or what points exist in some region

Comment: For me it looks like you are connecting to the center of the edges. So the closest point has either the same `x` or the same `y` coordinate. Then you can figure it out basically by list-sorting. And FWIW, constructions like ` z in range( len( lineStruct))` and then `cx = lineStruct[z][0]` more pythonic would go like `for z in lineStruct:` and `cx = z[0]`

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I have added an example to explain what I am trying to achieve. I would look into Scipy library, but the code I am working on in python would have to be ported to Kotlin on Android. I apologize if the explanation makes it seem like I am connecting to the center of the edges but the w and h points are the distance from the x and y points which would give me my x2, y2 points.

Comment: Can't you just compute the distance between each of a line's endpoints and the point in the rectangle to see which endpoint is closer? By the way, at the first link there's a little green dot in the top-left rectangle that looks a bit suspicious.

Comment: So that's what I am trying to do but the rectangle center points are connecting to the wrong end points. Also yeah in the first image I made a mistake in paint before I snipped the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is pretty hard to read and understand due to multiple nested `for`-loops.

A good practice is to structure the code using functions. Any operation that you can describe in an English sentence should be its own function. As much as possible, avoid nesting loops; instead, encapsulate the inner loop in a function with an explicit name that describes what this function does.

Note that you don't actually need to use `math.sqrt`, because minimizing the distance is equivalent to minimizing the squared distance.

```py
def squared_distance(p1, p2):
    (x1, y1) = p1
    (x2, y2) = p2
    return (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2

def get_closer_point(center, endpoints):
    x, y, w, h = endpoints
    p1 = (x, y)
    p2 = (x + w, y + h)
    if squared_distance(center, p1) <= squared_distance(center, p2):
        return p1
    else:
        return p2

def get_closer_points(center_list, endpoints_list):
    l = []
    for c, e in zip(center_list, endpoints_list):
        l.append(get_closer_point(c, e))
    return l

# TESTING
centers =   [(0,0), (37, 42), (18, 12)]
endpoints = [(1,0,0,1), (30,40,5,3), (20,20,-5,-5)]

closer_points = get_closer_points(centers, endpoints)
print('centers:   ', centers)
print('endpoints: ', endpoints)
print('closer:    ', closer_points)

# centers:    [(0, 0), (37, 42), (18, 12)]
# endpoints:  [(1, 0, 0, 1), (30, 40, 5, 3), (20, 20, -5, -5)]
# closer:     [(1, 0), (35, 43), (15, 15)]
```

Sidenote: instead of using our own function to calculate the distance between two points using Pythagoras' theorem, we can avoid reinventing the wheel and look for this function in python's standard library. As it turns out, there is `math.dist` which does exactly that. So, you can import `math.dist`, then replace every occurrence of `squared_distance` in the code above with `math.dist` instead. This is easy to do, since we've already encapsulated `squared_distance` as a function; it would be much more annoying to do if we had written Pythagoras' formula explicitly everytime we needed it.